# How to refresh array to render Angular?

Tags: angular

I set array using this:

```
@Input() sogllist: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listService.setItems([...this.sogllist]);
}
```

Getter to display in template is:

```
public get sogllistToRender() {
    return this.listService.getItems();
}
```

When user removes an array from array I return filtered array excluding deleted element:

```
public delete(sogl){
    this.listService.setItems([...this.sogllist.filter((s) => s.userid !== sogl.userid)]);
}
```

Why template does not render it again:

```
 *ngFor="let sogl of sogllistToRender"
```

**List service is:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ListService {
    public onChanged = new Subject<any[]>();
    private items: any[] = [];

    getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    setItems(items: any): void {
        this.items = items;
    }

    setSelected(value: any): void {
        value.selected = !value.selected;
    }

    setSelectedState(value: any, state: boolean): void {
        value.selected = state;
    }

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        moveItemInArray(this.items, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        return [...this.items];
    }

    emitChnages(): void {
        this.onChanged.next(this.items);
    }
}
```

**Last changes:**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        // Set input array to service 
        this.listService.setItems([...this.sogllist]);

        // Get data from service and apply to local component variable
        this.sogllistToRender = this.listService.getItems();
    }
```

Update current array after remove:

```
 this.sogllistToRender = [...this.sogllist.filter((s) => s.userid !== sogl.userid)];
```

Comment: you need to provide more details, how are you deleting, how you have used in template etc

Comment: if `sogllistToRender` returns a new value, that will render for sure, there is something wrong with your code, update the question with more relevant code to be able to get help.

Comment: Yeah.. not enough here.. show you listService maybe?

Comment: I have posted alll code, I delete using `[...this.sogllist.filter((s) => s.userid !== sogl.userid)]`, see my code

Comment: Okay, I will post now listService

Comment: All components have onPush strategy

Comment: What if `sogllistToRender` returns `[...this.listService.getItems()]`?

Comment: Does not work, only when used focuses on list it is disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular will observe for changes in component state and will re-render if any changes are made (That's why ngOnChanges lifecycle exists).

However Angular will observe only changes in that component not in some service that holds a state.

So if you want to always render the last state of the array make an array field in your component and update that instead of keeping the array into a service.

If state must be inside a service so that other component can access it, then you can create another array in your component and load it's value from your service array.

Comment: Still does not work:        `this.sogllistToRender = this.listService.getItems();   this.sogllistToRender = this.sogllist.filter((s) => s.userid !== sogl.userid);`

Comment: where do you do this? You must do it after you set the array in ngOnInit. One line after you make the set array in ngOnInit

Comment: I have updated my question where I do this. look please

Comment: this.sogllistToRender = [...this.sogllist.filter((s) => s.userid !== sogl.userid)]; You don't need the three dots here. filter creates new array anyways. Try with this.sogllistToRender = this.sogllist.filter((s) => s.userid !== sogl.userid)

Comment: If it still does not render any changes then I see 2 possibilities. A) The filtered array is the same as before. Nothing get's filtered in your filter function. B) You have made some changes with how angular detect changes during your previous search and configurations. If all are set to default and A is not true it should render those changes

Comment: To check this I tried: ` this.sogllistToRender = [];` no rendering

Comment: can you please upload all affected code and not parts of this. Then we have more chances of locating the error

Comment: Element is deleted only when user click in area of list

Comment: in one comment you have said `All components have onPush strategy – Aurica 1 hour ago`. Therefore as I said B case is true. Revert for those affected components the default change strategy and it should work